# filter common substring for enum keys in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I have two enum maps and looking to make an array for the enum keys removing the common substring in the array so I can use it for other enum Maps as well.
enum format is as

```
enum Test {
   test_value_error = 1;
   test_value_log = 2;
   test_value_main = 3;
   test_value_acknowledge = 4;}
```

```
enum Test1 {
   short_set_measure = 5;
   short_set_log_check = 6;
   short_set_finite_check = 7;}

in this case I want to remove common substring from two enum map using a common function and convert it to array. So far I have been able to filter it to array format but can't filter out substring. 
below is my code.
```

function toArray(enumname: object) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(key => key.replace(/_/g, ' '));}

```
Still new to typescript so any help will be beneficial
```

Comment: Where do you define `obj`?

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

Are you look for this?

```
enum Test {
  test_value_error = 1,
  test_value_log = 2,
  test_value_main = 3,
  test_value_acknowledge = 4
}

function toArray(enumname: object) {
  return Object.keys(enumname).map(key => key.replace(/test_value/g, ""));
}

const arr = toArray(Test);

console.log(arr);
```

It removes the `test_value` from each key. The output looks like this:

```
[ '1', '2', '3', '4', '_error', '_log', '_main', '_acknowledge' ]
```

## Alternatives

```
// [ '1', '2', '3', '4', 'error', 'log', 'main', 'acknowledge' ]
function toArray(enumname: object) {
  return Object.keys(enumname).map(key => key.replace(/test\_value\_/g, ""));
}

// [ 'error', 'log', 'main', 'acknowledge' ]
function toArray(enumname: object) {
  return Object.keys(enumname)
    .filter(key => !parseInt(key))
    .map(key => key.replace(/test\_value\_/g, ""));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shaun Luttin for the advice. What if there are multiple enum maps and if I have to run my typescript function in order to remove common substring then I cannot hard code. Is there any other way to find common substring and remove from array